# CSS Scroll Text Initial Scroll Position

Tags: css

I would like to set the the initial scroll position of my `.audio_player_scroll` to `0%` so it's in frame when it starts scroll.  Then on subsequent passes I would like it to start scrolling from `100%`.  Both of these are reflected in the code below, but the animation always starts scrolling at `100%` instead of the `0%` which I want for the first time (I want the scrolling text to start in frame instead of out).  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
.audio_player_scroll
     position absolute  
     margin 0
     text-align left
     /* Apply animation to this element */  
     animation  scroll-left 10s linear infinite
     animation-delay 1.5s
     transform translateX(0%)

@keyframes scroll-left {
     0%   { 
       transform: translateX(100%);         
     }
     100% { 
       transform: translateX(-100%); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippets that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

Why it shouldn't start from 100%? Your transform: translateX(0%); is for before animation start. Set you **animation-delay** to a large value to see before animation it is translateX(0%).

But once animation starts it goes to translateX(100%) as your code.

You can change your animation keyframes:

```
@keyframes scroll-left {
 0%   { 
   transform: translateX(0%);         
 }
 25%   { 
   transform: translateX(100%);         
 }
 75% { 
   transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
 100%   { 
   transform: translateX(0%);         
 }
}
```